# Issue in using xamarin.andriod JNI to call activity from android AAR file

Tags: xamarin.android, java-native-interface, jnienv, xamarin-binding

Hi I am facing using AAR file in xamarin android project . I have added android AAR file in my xamarin android and set its build type to "AndroidAarLibrary" .Following is c# code used in xamarin to call activity that is defined in AAR file.

```
var clsName = Java.Lang.Class.ForName("com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.activity.DsPhotoEditorActivity");
var innt = new Intent(this, clsName);
innt.SetData(inputImageUri); //Set image uri
innt.PutExtra("ds_photo_editor_api_key", "26c479d17c220131bec7b6e29e070ad89f3e6cf4");
innt.PutExtra("ds_photo_editor_output_directory", "ds_photo_editor_sample");
StartActivityForResult(innt, DS_PHOTO_EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Now corresponding activity is called successfully and UI showing image editor property. But when clicking filter options in UI then it throw error and application gets closed with follwing error message:

CheckJNI: method to register "rsnScriptReduce" not in the given class. This is slow, consider changing your RegisterNatives calls.
Failed to register native method android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptReduce(JJI[JJ[I)V in /data/app/mono.samples.jnitest-1/base.apk
 ----- class 'Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;' cl=0x32c07070 -----

I think some classes not included while apk generation or not accessible. Please let me know if I am doing anything or if anyone have used this approach before.
This is google drive link to corresponding xamarin project https://drive.google.com/open?id=13r5FPLhbf75ERBqJI858kubmVARitZ74

Link of full log file of xamarin output : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1doDkuUR7P25TfBfGz_QHn3m_TsGQ3MNo

Note:I am want to use photo-editor AAR library from https://www.dsphotoeditor.com

Comment: does your project include https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportv8 ?

Comment: Yes I have added it.Infact I have added all dependencicies that are declred in AAR file. FOllwiing are referecens I have added :

Comment: Yes I have added infect I have added all dependencies that are declared in AAR file. Following are references I have added :
Xamarin.Android.Support.v8.RenderScript
RxJava2
Picasso
Xamarin.andriod.support.v7.AppCompat
Volley

I this issue is registering native function present in Failed to register native method android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.rsnScriptReduce(JJI[JJ[I)V . I dont know why its not working . Because same AAR file working perfectly in android sample code here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PY39GUsisOaaNNQBIhDWg1y6pfLxzpDr/view

Comment: The sample app works for you on the same device?

Comment: Yes its works perfectly on same device. But when I use AAR file and access it using Xamarin c# jNI then some functionality works some not. You can check build and run xamarin project from this URL  https://drive.google.com/open?id=13r5FPLhbf75ERBqJI858kubmVARitZ74